# How do you convert a user unputted integer into a variable on Python?

Tags: python, variables, input, python-3.x, integer

I am trying to make a program to calculate final grades. The user inputs x amount of assignments, and based on that I am looking to make x variables asking for the grade recieved and the weight of each assignment. 
For example,
(user selects 20 assignments)
(as input):
enter assignment1 grade received,
enter assignment2 grade received,
...............
enter assignment20 grade received.     (and the same for weights)

There needs to be a variable per assignment and I am unsure how to essentially convert an integer into a variable. (lists are not allowed).
Please feel free to offer suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
numAssigns = input("How many assignments?: ")
marks = {}

for i in range(numAssignments):
    mark = input("Enter the grade obtained on assignment %s: " %i)
    weight = input("Enter the weight of assignment %s: " %i)/100
    if weight not in marks:
        marks[weight] = {}
    if mark not in marks[weight]:
        marks[weight][mark] = 0
    marks[weight][mark] += 1

total = 0
for weight in marks:
    for mark in marks[weight]
        total += mark*weight*marks[weight][mark]
print("From all your assignments, you have %s% of the total grade of the course" %total)
```

Comment: In the question, it states "(lists are not allowed)".